# Convert List to JSON Array

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to convert the following manually typed JSON list to a List I can load, but still output the same format in C#, so in can be POSTed to a REST API.

```
var accs = @"{
        " + "\n" +
          @"    ""Cities"": [                
        " + "\n" +
          @"        ""Atlanta"",
        " + "\n" +
          @"        ""Chicago"",
        " + "\n" +
          @"        ""San Diego""
        " + "\n" +
          @"    ]
        " + "\n" +
          @"}
        " + "\n" +
          @"";
```

Comment: I think first you need to find out who manually typed this code and have some harsh words with them

Comment: @Jonesopolis This is not a nice comment. Maybe he is new to C# and showed us how he initially handled the problem and tries to find a clean solution.

Comment: When you use `@"`, you can avoid the `+` concatenation and just put your JSON on multiple lines. Use `'` instead of `"` in your JSON text.

Comment: @ˈvɔlə I'm sorry - I didn't mean for it to be anything but satirical.  We (especially me) are all guilty of writing questionable code.  I see people on this site get way too serious sometimes and it's nice to be able to have a quick laugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your model:

```
public class State
    {
        public List<string> Cities { get; set; }

        public State(List<string> cities)
        {
            Cities = cities;
        }
    }
```

This is how you serialize and deserialize:

```
using System.Text.Json;

var listOfCities = new List<string>() { "Atlanta", "Chicago", "San Diego"};

var state = new State(listOfCities);

//Serialize
var jsonArray = JsonSerializer.Serialize(state);

// Deserialize
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<State>(jsonArray);
```

Comment: I don't understand why a city contains cities.

Comment: It's not the point really... not my main language so it wasn't intuitive for me.
Changed it, I hope its ok like this.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@"`, you can avoid the `+` concatenation like:

```cs
var accs = @"
{
  'Cities': [
    'Atlanta',
    'Chicago',
    'San Diego'
  ]
}
";
```

You'll need to use `'` (single quotes) instead of `"` in your JSON text, otherwise you have to escape `\"` them.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any custom classes, you can just parse your json string

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 var jsonParsed=JObject.Parse(accs);
```

if you need list of cities as c# instance

```
 List<string> cities =jsonParsed["Cities"].ToObject<List<string>>();
```

if you need just  a well formatted json string

```
 accs = jsonParsed.ToString();
```

result

```
{
  "Cities": [
    "Atlanta",
    "Chicago",
    "San Diego"
  ]
}
```